# Unable to decode json array after sending it via exec in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, exec

I have an `array` that looks like this:

**Daemon.php**

```
$data = array(

   'notificationId' => $notificationId,
   'userId' => $userId,
   'appId' => $appId,
   'message' => $message,
   'destinationUrl' => $destinationUrl,
   'method' => $method,
   'notificationTime' => $notificationTime,
   'timeReceived' => $timeReceived,
   'impressions' => $impressions,
   'clicks' => $clicks,
   'numberOfUsers' => $numberOfUsers,
   'campaignId' => $campaignId,
   'targetGroups' => $targetGroups,
   'notificationType' => $notificationType,
   'status' => $status,
   'appGroup' => $appGroup

);
```

That I'm sending via `exec` like so:

```
$data=json_encode($data);
exec("php path/where/script/is/useArray.php ".$data." &");
```

And trying to use it like so on other script:

**useArray.php**

```
$logData=$argv[1];
json_decode($logData);
```

In order to see which data received on `useArray.php` I'm putting this `$logData` array into txt file on server like this:

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__ .'/log/testiranje.txt', print_r($logData,true)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

But sent `json` just seem not to be decoded right. This is how this `$logData` looks inside `testiranje.txt`:

```
{notificationId:478,userId:92,appId:1512823699024883,message:joj,destinationUrl:https:\/\/www.servis-racunara.net\/pages\/,method:2}
```

So this is some strange json-alike format that I got after doing `json_decode`. And of course I don't know how to use this format, because I can't do anything like:

```
$notificationId   = $logData['notificationId'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interpreting a string through the shell syntax, which has its own very large and complex set of **special characters**. For one, `"` quotes are interpreted by the shell and are consequently stripped out of the resulting value.

If you want to transport any arbitrary string through the shell (or in fact through any intermediary language which has its own syntax and special characters), you need to **escape** it appropriately:

```
exec("php path/where/script/is/useArray.php " . escapeshellarg($data) . " &");
```

See http://php.net/escapeshellarg.

Having said this, I'd avoid this kind of invocation to begin with and use other communication mechanisms, like a queue/worker setup using ØMQ, Gearman or the like. But that's out of scope for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't normally type random characters in a shell and get them pass through as regular text, that's why [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) exists (though in my experience it only works correctly on Unix shells and often fails terribly on Windows).

In any case, command line arguments are only appropriate for small parameters. If you need to transmit complex data you'd better use other mechanisms:

- Standard input
- Temporary files

For the former, you'll have to dump `exec()` and use e.g. `proc_open()`—you can find usage examples in the [manual page](http://php.net/proc_open).

For the latter, just pick your favourite among [file system functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php). For small files, the `file_put_contents()` / `file_get_contents()` combo is probably just fine.